# Can you search for the difference between neighbouring bytes in IDA?

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I am looking for a specific string hidden inside the .exe file (32-bit, standard options). I know that this string has had ROT-?? applied to it and I know the string, therefore I wanted to search for its occurence using difference between the bytes. Is it possible in IDA? If not or there is a better way, what would you recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using YARA rules. You write a rule using `xor` [modifier](https://yara.readthedocs.io/en/stable/writingrules.html?highlight=xor#xor-strings)
Then you can scan your binary. If you still want to do it inside IDA Pro you can install a plugin like [findcrypt-yara](https://github.com/polymorf/findcrypt-yara) and add your rule in it.